# $\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda(n)[N/n]=[\sqrt{N}]$ Identity involving Liouville Lambda function

Tags: summation, analytic-number-theory, liouville-function

I have to prove $$\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda(n)[N/n]=[\sqrt{N}]$$ I tried using the approach in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/875509/a-m%C3%B6bius-identity) question but I don't know how I'll get $\sqrt{N}$. Please help.

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8002, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332588

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\sum_{n=1}^N\lambda(n)[N/n] =\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{d|n}\lambda(d) $$

Next use [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/516153/liouville-function-and-perfect-square) to conclude that the double sum equals the number of perfect squares not exceeding $N$

Comment: Can you explain how you convert it into a double sum?

Comment: Notice that for a fixed $n$, on the left hand side the function  $\lambda(n)$ is getting evaluated  $[N/n]$ times. On the right hand side also the specific term $\lambda(n)$ appears exactly $[N/n]$ times in the expanded sum because the number of integers divisible by $n$ is $[N/n]$

Comment: More generally we have below for any number theoretic function $f$ :  $$\sum_{n=1}^N f(n) [N/n] =\sum_{n=1}^N\sum_{d|n}f(d)$$